# faild to build Libyuv library (PJSIP) for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip, libyuv, openh264

I'm developing a chat android application. I want to use also the call functionality. I have successfully built the pjsua2.so library for SIP call VoIP but I failed to build Libyuv.so Library for video call

I followed the instructions in thows to links
[libyuv building](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#Requirements1) [libyuv 1776](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1776)

After running ndk-build command in step 2 from the second link, I do not have this lib libyuv. So I don't have also [libyuv_dir]/libs/armeabi

Also for openH264, after runnig this command `/configure-android --with-openh264=/home/ubuntu/openh264-1.0.0/android`  I got that :

> Using OpenH264 prefix... /home/ubuntu/PJSIPTOOLS/openh264-1.0.0/openlib/
> checking OpenH264 usability... no

Can anybody help me please
(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Download and build libyuv from here:
https://github.com/illuspas/libyuv-android

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i download it from that link ! but dosen't work for me @manao

Comment: And did you run ndk from libyuv-android folder? What errors it htrows?

Comment: yes yes, i run it from libyuv-android folder, i got this folder libyuv-android/obj/local who contains those folders arm64-v8a armeabi-v7a x86 x86_64 and i do not find the lib libyuv.so i got libyuv.a into those folders @manao

Comment: Well as i can see libyuv-android was updated few month ago. You can take older version(version before last commit). I've just builded it and libs foder is present there.

Comment: can you give me link to download the older version ? i got it from this link https://github.com/illuspas/libyuv-android and doesn't work

Comment: https://github.com/illuspas/libyuv-android/tree/043741684af0df6401a73a60424d4da84fe6781d

Comment: thanks ! i got finaly the library libyuv.so into the libs folder !

Comment: but i got this problem too

Using OpenH264 prefix... /Users/me/openh264-1.0.0/android
checking OpenH264 usability... no
Using libyuv prefix... /Users/me/libyuv-android/jni
checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... no

Comment: Did you put libyuv.so in jni/out/Release folder? And enable video feature in config_site.h?

Comment: Just successful configure pjsip with this string ./configure-android --with-openh264='/home/user/Desktop/Ooo/android' --with-libyuv='/home/user/Desktop/Ooo/libyuv-android/jni'. Have now idea why it doesn't work in your case.

Comment: too bad for me ! can i get the PJSUA2 project with video call please ? i got it without video call just voice call

Comment: Here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5CXN1kiJw35bnhFRC1tWDZoT2s/view?pref=2&pli=1